# I am facing errors with npm install command

Tags: angularjs-directive

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Mohlomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Mohlomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1: node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\Mohlomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Mohlomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohlomi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-10T14_50_39_626Z-debug.
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the existing file and try again, or run `npm` with `--force` to overwrite files recklessly?

Comment: I have tried but still erroring